# How much energy from extreme coldness?

Tags: thermodynamics

Let's say I have:

1: one mole of extremely cold ideal gas
2: unlimited amount of ideal gas at temperature 300 K
3: one ideal heat engine

Can I generate for example 1 MWh of mechanical energy using those three things?

Alternative formulation: When temperature of the cold gas approaches 0 K, what does the amount of generated energy approach?

(there is no other heat sink than one mole of cold ideal gas)

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I just saw John Rennie post his answer, but he  seems to assume that all the heat flow $\delta Q$, which comes from the hot bath, translates to the $\delta Q$, which eventually heats up the cold gas via $\delta Q=C dT$. I'm interested in clearing that up.

[image]

I think this is the  way to go:

We have the efficiency
$$\eta:=\frac{\delta W}{\delta Q_{\text{bath}}}=1-\frac{T_{\text{low}}}{T_{bath}},$$
and
$$\delta  Q_{\text{low}}=C\ dT,$$
and of course 
$$dU=\delta Q_{\text{bath}}-(\delta Q_{\text{low}}+\delta W)=0.$$
$$\Longrightarrow \left(\frac{\delta Q_{\text{bath}}}{\delta W}-1\right)\delta W=\delta Q_{\text{low}}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \delta W=C\ dT\times \left(\frac{T_{\text{bath}}}{T_{\text{low}}}-1\right)$$

If you use your machine it open up the heat channel and translates $\delta Q_{\text{bath}}$ to work as long as the initially cold gas hasn't warmed up to bath temperature. In case you start out with $T_{\text{low}}=T_{\text{bath}}$, then nothing will happen.

$$\Delta W=\int_{\epsilon>0}^{T_{\text{bath}}}C\ T_{bath}\left(\frac{1}{T}-\frac{1}{T_{bath}}\right)dT=C\ T_{\text{bath}}\times \left(\text{log}\left({\frac{T_{\text{bath}}}{\epsilon}}\right)-\frac{T_{\text{bath}}-\epsilon}{T_{\text{bath}}}\right).$$

Here the first factor $C\ T_{\text{bath}}$ would be the energy from the direct heating of the cold gas.

Edit: To point that out more clearly, the term $-C\ T_{\text{bath}}\ \text{log}(\epsilon)$ in this ideal model is arbitrary big. Whenever you half the small minimal temperature, you get another constant amount of work $W$ out of the machine.

Comment: Oops yes, that's what comes of doing things in a hurry. If your mole of gas was really at absolute zero (impossible of course) all the heat flow will go into work and you'd get an infinite amout of work out. I'll hurriedly delete my answer before someone downvotes it!

Comment: but you have not given numbers. My instinctive reply would be that no, you cannot get 1MWh out of this set up.1 Megawatt is 3.6*10^9 joule/h http://www.unitconversion.org/power/megawatts-to-joules-per-hour-conversion.html.

Comment: @anna v: If I didn't make a calculation mistake, then the expression says that depending on $C$ and $\epsilon$, you can get any amount of work from an infinite heat reservoir this way. The rate $dT=\frac{dQ_{\text{low}}}{C}=\frac{\delta Q_{\text{bath}}-\delta W}{C}$ means that for very big $C$, the cold gas will take forever to warm up, while for very small $T_{\text{low}}$, the efficiency of converting $Q_{\text{bath}}$ to work is quasi $1:1$. In any case, in practice this will never work, since $C$, or rather $C(T)$ and also $\eta(T)$ are more complicated than the expressions for ideal gas.

Comment: @anna v: The main point being that the third law of thermodynamics says something about $C(T)$ at low temperatures, namely that it should be very very small and certainly not constant.

Comment: but,but,but, the question says that there is only one mole of the extremely cold gas, that will reach the temperature of the bath and that will be it.

Comment: @anna v: What are you saying? Whatever the constant $C$ is, for arbitrary low gas temperatures $\epsilon$, the $log(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ term will make $W$ arbitrary big.

Comment: and you have no problem with energy conservation? I am very rusty on this and cannot check your assumptions, but when paradoxes arise ( one mole taking an indefinitely large energy up) then the assumed relations have to be checked at those limits.

Comment: @anna v: I think you havent really checked what's going on. 1. there is an infinite heat reservoir 2. the one mole only eats energy $C\Delta T$, but as you see in the graphic representing the heat engine, the one mole is only there so the heats starts flowing. Point is: If the cold gas has high $C$ and takes a lot of heat (i.e. "takes a long time to heat up"), while the machine simultaneously has high $\eta$, so it translates more energy to work than goes into the cold gas, then there will flow a lot of heat from the bath. Some (namely $C\Delta T$) goes to he gas, but the majority becomes $W$.

Comment: I don't like maths, but I like this answer. So I guess cooling one mole of stuff very close to 0 K requires gigajoules of energy. Halving the temperature of an object takes a constant amount of energy, that is proportional to amount of substance and the temperature where the waste heat is dumped. This way the laws of thermodynamics can stay intact.

Comment: @kartsa: Ya, well to cool something down you always need something which is even cooler and this might be a problem. Also, as I said in the comments, the ideal gas assumption certainly doesn't hold in these exreme conditions. To avoid things like the situation in this question, by the third law the heat capacity $C$ of a gas has to go to zero with lower temperatures, i.e. $C(T)$ is an a priori unknown function of $T$ and so you can't in general perform the integral without knowing it.

Comment: Late here, but to complete the answer: at low temperatures specific heat of solids (you won't have a gas, though you could have liquid helium) scales with $T^3$, so plugging that into your last integral (instead of assuming $C$ is constant) gives $\Delta W=12\pi^4/5 N k_B (T_{bath}/T_D)^3$, where $T_D$ is the Debye temperature for your material and $N$ the number of atoms. This works for small $T_{bath}$ as $C$ only scales with $T^3$ at low temperature. At higher temperatures it levels off. So, the work you get out is finite, and on the order of a few tens of joules for any real material.

Comment: My equation above may be out by a factor of 12. It should be $\Delta W=\pi^4/5 N k_B (T_{bath}/T_D)^3$, unless I am mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

(Nick Kidman was a bit faster but I post my coffee break answer anyway)

I doubt that you can extract 1 MWh from your experiment but let's see: We start with an ideal engine that runs with the Carnot efficiency: $$\eta=1-\frac{T_{cold}}{T_{warm}}$$
So if you have one mole of extremely cold gas the initial efficiency of the ideal engine will be very high, still you will warm up the cold reservoir. For one mole of an ideal gas the specific heat at constant volume is $$C_v = \frac{3}{2}R \approx 12 \frac{J}{K}$$
The energy you can extract from your machine is $$dE = dQ_{warm} \cdot \eta(T_{cold})$$The heat going into your cold gas is $$dQ_{cold} = \frac{T_{cold}}{T_{warm}} dQ_{warm}$$ With $C= dQ/T$ we can calculate the total energy
$$E = \int C\left(\frac{T_{warm}}{T_{cold}} - 1 \right) dT_{cold}$$With a mole of very cold gas at 1mK and a room temperature bath at 300K Wolfram Alpha thinks we are able to extract 41kJ out of this machine and as we can see the efficiency drops rapidly when the cold gas warms up:
[image]