# Why is $0 \,\mathrm{K}$ so special?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I know that $0 \,\mathrm{K}$ cannot be reached, this is discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32830/) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81589/).

But, why is it such an important statement?

I mean, there are many properties which will never be zero, like: acceleration, torque, force, etc. But these facts are almost never discussed. Is it because the  absolute temperature has stronger implications?

Comment: What makes you believe acceleration can never be zero?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi If EM and gravity have infinite range, $F=ma$ indicates that $a \neq 0$

Comment: For EM waves, m = 0, therefore, $p = \hbar k$, $F = dp/dt$

Comment: @Programmer I was thinking of Classical Mechanics, but you're right in that case.

Comment: Even classically, if I coast up from one gravity well and down into another one my acceleration due to gravity in the direction of motion surely passed through zero along the way. Getting the transverse value also zero takes more work but the central value theorem *guarantees* that is it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments have mentioned, acceleration, torque and force can all be zero, but the key point is that some zeros are more fundamental than others.

Take acceleration: you state in a comment that Newton's law of gravity has an infinite range so the force/acceleration generated by some gravitating body can never be zero. This is quite true, but acceleration/force can be positive or negative so two non-zero accelerations can sum to zero. This is what dmckee means in his comment. Even though the gravitational fields of the Earth and Moon are infinite, somewhere in between them is a point where the net force is zero.

But (ignoring some technical definitions) you can't have a negative temperature. So I can't take a chunk of matter and make it's temperature zero by mixing it with another chunk of matter that has a negative temperature. The only way I can cool my chunk of matter is by putting it in contact with something that is colder, but of course still has a positive temperature.

So 0K is special because there is nothing colder than it.